# How to iterate the following code in jsp?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, mapping

I have written a method inside Daoimpl  and returning the list to my jsp. Can anyone tell how to iterate and print the values of the  list in my jsp???

**Error:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.bdisys.promorphics.domain.Blog
```

**Dao Method**:In this dao method I am writing a query and returning the result to jsp and anyone tell me how to print these values?

```
    public Map<String, Date> getTopBlogsQuesByDate()throws Exception {
             List<Blog> blogs = new ArrayList<Blog>(0);
             Map<String, Date> map = new HashMap<String, Date>();
             try{



                    String sql = "select title , date from (select blog_title as title ,created_date as date from  blog  union select ask_question as title , created_on as date from askquestions ) as aa order by date desc";
                    SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
                    query.setResultTransformer(AliasToBeanResultTransformer); 


                    List l =query.list();
                    System.out.println("Total Number Of Records : "+l.size());
                    Iterator it = l.iterator();

                    while(it.hasNext())
                    {
                        Object o = (Object) it.next();
                        Blog b = (Blog)o;
                        b.setBlogTitle(b.getBlogTitle());
                        b.setCreatedDate(b.getCreatedDate());
                        map.put(b.getBlogTitle(), b.getCreatedDate());
                        System.out.println("Blog title Name : "+b.getBlogTitle());
                        System.out.println("Blog Date : "+b.getCreatedDate());

                        Askquestions a = (Askquestions)o;
                        a.setAskQuestion(a.getAskQuestion());
                        a.setCreatedQuesOn(a.getCreatedQuesOn());
                        System.out.println("Question title Name : "+a.getAskQuestion());
                        System.out.println("Question Date : "+a.getCreatedQuesOn());


                        map.put(a.getAskQuestion(), a.getCreatedQuesOn());

                        System.out.println("Unsorted HashMap: " + map);
                        TreeMap<String, Date> sortedHashMap = new TreeMap(map);     
                        System.out.println("Sorted HashMap: " + sortedHashMap); 

                    }        


             }
  catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                closeSession();
            }
         return map;
    }
```

Comment: what you are extracting from the DB is not a `Blog` it is simple an Object array containing two fields.

Comment: BTW, this does not look like JSP to me

Comment: do you want to print the content of sortedHashMap in your DOA java method??

Comment: Note that query.list() is invoked twice. Bit of careless programming done here.

Comment: @user2310289 yes and i want it to print the values of them in my jsp.and as i clearly mentioned this is not my jsp its my dao method.

Comment: @zeeshan no i am returning map to jsp and i want to print them in jsp.

Comment: @SalmanAmaan, I have given an answer for iterating though a hashMap in a jsp.

Answer (score 1):

For printing a `hashMap` in a jsp you can can use JSTL **forEach**

```
<c:forEach items="${myMap}" var="entry">
    Key : <c:out value="${entry.key}"/>  Value: <c:out value="${entry.value}"/> <br />
</c:forEach>
```

It iterates over the hashmap, and returns the EntrySet. And you can then use its getKey() and getValue() method

**Note:**

1. Add jstl library to your classpath,
2. Add `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>` in your jsp top.

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed class to the `AliasToBeanResultTransformer`.

Change

```
query.setResultTransformer(AliasToBeanResultTransformer);
```

To

```
query.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Blog.class));
```

#### See also

- [AliasToBeanResultTransformer docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/transform/AliasToBeanResultTransformer.html)

Comment: i have two classes blog and askquestions..how to pass them ??

Comment: @SalmanAmaan : Don't know about two classes because `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` takes only one parameter.

Comment: can we pass them separately??